# Induced $\ell^2$ norm for a rank-three tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, tensor-products, tensors, matrix-norms

Given an $n\times m$ matrix $A$, its $\ell^2$ induced norm is defined as
$$
\|A\|_I = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^m, x\neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}.
$$
Given a rank-three tensor $B$ with dimensions $n\times m\times p$ is it possible to define a similar induced norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, given a tensor $B\in V_1\otimes V_2\otimes V_3$, where $V_i$'s are all normed spaces (over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, and if there is any problem with what follows, just assume they are all finite dimensional with an inner product), considered as multilinear map from $V_1^*,V_2^*, V_3^*$ to the scalar field, then we can define its norm by $$\|B\|:=\sup_{v_i\in V_i^*\setminus\{0\}}\frac{|B(v_1, v_2, v_3)|}{\|v_1\|\|v_2\|\|v_3\|}$$

Note that this definition generalized the original definition for norms on matrices, since $\|Ax\|_2=\sup_{y\in\mathbb R^n} \frac{|(Ax, y)|}{\|y\|}$

This definition can be generalized to tensors of any dimensions.

In particular, when $B$ is indeed a vector from a normed space $V$, then the defintion will not change the norm of $B$ on $V$, since we have the isometric embedding $V\hookrightarrow V^{**}$.

Comment: In the second display is $(Ax, y)$ a typo?

Comment: Right. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am still confused about $(Ax, y)$... the numerator in the matrix norm is defined as $\sqrt{\langle Ax, Ax \rangle}$

Comment: We'd like to regard the vector $Ax$ as a linear functional, and in the case of $2$-norms, this can be done by $y\mapsto (Ax,y)$, the inner product of $Ax$ and $y$. Note that the norm of $Ax$ as a functional is the same as its norm as a vector. That's the point of the last paragraph (in a more general context, where the norm isn't necessarily induced by an inner product)

Comment: The formula given in the answer is the same as $\sqrt{(Ax, Ax)}$. Indeed, by Cauchy-Schwarz $|(Ax,y)|/\|y\|\le \|Ax\|\|y\|/\|y\|=\|Ax\|$, and let $y=Ax$, we know that $\sqrt{(Ax,Ax)}$ can be achieved by the $\sup$.

Comment: Aaah I see, thanks! Given this definition of induced norm, would it be possible to generalize what it means for $B$ to be Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: All these are about linear functions/operators, and linearity always implies Lipschitz continuity.